# Rails Search Box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

So I have a search box working in my application, however it only returns a result if the search matches exactly what is submitted, as opposed to something like it. Heres my code for the search method;

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        where(:title => ["title LIKE ?", "#{search}"])
    else
        all
    end
end
```

The "title LIKE ?" doesn't seem to be returning results which are like the query, only ones which are exactly the same.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have also tried where(["title LIKE ?", "#{search}"])

Comment: i'd suggest you to use something like sphinx or elasticsearch. They are easy to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
where(["title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way if you want to avoid string queries (using arel):

```
where(arel_table[:title].matches("%#{search}%"))
```